# Connecting to Bluetooth device via NFC Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, core-nfc

I am working on an App to attempt to automatically connect to a bluetooth device after tapping an NFC button. My original thought of implementing it was to grab the device UUID from NFC, and then attempt to connect in the background. However, if there are any encrypted characteristics this could cause issues as a pairing request would pop up, and I want to avoid that and make the connection as seamless as possible. Is this even possible on iOS, and is there any documentation on this? I have found almost no resources to help, but it seems as there are speakers/headphones out there that have implemented this.

Any idea on where to begin looking would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: NFC pairing/connection is not supported natively on iOS.  To complicate matters further, the device MAC address is not visible to apps on iOS.  You could put the device name in the NFC tag and then the app would scan for devices and identify the appropriate device using that name from the advertisement data.

Comment: What do you mean by the device name? If I just go by the device name there would be the possibility that it wouldn't be a unique value right? Is there an identifier I could use that would ensure is unique to each device? Thanks @Paulw11

Comment: Only if you can include some data in the advertising packet, which will depend on the control you have over your device firmware and Bluetooth stack. There is limited information available to an app without actually making a connection to a device and reading a characteristic.  iOS doesn’t provide a unique identifier for a device that is consistent across devices. I.e. each iOS device gets a different unique identifier for a given peripheral